# How to convert Unix date time into seconds in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

If i have a column like this

[image]

How would i convert this into seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In PowerQuery change the type of the column to Date/Time
2. Add a Custom Column with the formula
   `= ([business_duration] - #datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)) * 24 * 60 * 60`
3. Change the type of the new column to Whole Number

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```fs
let
    fun_DateTimeFromUnix = (DateTime as number) as datetime =>
        let
            Source = #datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0) + #duration(0,0,0,DateTime)
        in
            Source
in
    fun_DateTimeFromUnix
```

As shown:

[image]

[image]